# very new to the programming and at the little exercise I cannot see where I am wrong

Tags: java, boolean, primitive

So maybe many of you knows the exercise we need to do about learning primitives, where we need to print h3110 w0r1d 2.0 true

so mine is this;

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // H3110 w0r1d 2.0 true
    byte bir = 0;
    short iki = 31;
    int uc = 10;
    long dort = 1;
    float bes = 2.0f;
    char yedi = 'H';
    char sekiz = 'w';
    char dokuz = 'd';
    char ekstra = ' ';
    char ramk = 'r';
    boolean on = true;

    String son = (yedi + iki + uc + ekstra + sekiz + bir + ramk + dort + dokuz + ekstra + bes + ekstra + on );
    System.out.println(son);







}
```

}

and their solution is this;

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte zero = 0;
    short a = 3;
    int b = 1;
    char d = ' ';
    float e = 2.0f;
    boolean f = true;
    String output = "H" + a + b + b + zero + d + "w" + zero + "r" + b + "d" + d + e + d + f;
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

}

So mine is giving me boolean and float errors, but I cant see what is wrong with that primitives.

the error Im getting is this

```
Main.java:16: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
    String son = (yedi + iki + uc + ekstra + sekiz + bir + ramk + dort + dokuz + ekstra + bes + ekstra + on );
                                                                                                       ^
```

first type:  float
  second type: boolean
1 error

Comment: Generally, when asking for help, you should include the error messages you're getting. It's a great help to others when trying to understand your problem.

Comment: Just so you know, I can't immediately imagine any reason I would subject a new programmer to such an exercise. If your teacher is setting you tasks like this, and if you have an option, find a better teacher.

Comment: I dont have a teacher, this exercise is from learnjavaonline.org, and Im now editing the error

Comment: I would move on to a tutorial doing something useful rather than ridiculously abstract and pointless. (No downvote here, btw)

Comment: but still, can I learn why the "example" code is working and mine doesnt?
also can you suggest another source for learning basic java then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
String son = (yedi + iki + uc ...
```

assigns a concatenation of multiple parameters of different types, none of which is a string, into a string.

The "solution" is to start the assignment by concatenating a string to the other parameters:

```
String output = "H" + a + b + ...
                 ^
```

which will cast the rest of them - to strings.

You can do the same with the first example by adding an empty string at the beginning:

```
String son = ("" + yedi + iki + uc ...
              ^
```

*Side-Note*: I totally agree with  T.J. Crowder's comment above...

Comment: thank you for your answer. but now I dont understand why it said "boolean" and "float" spesifically in the errror

Comment: @OktayMert look back at the types that are declared for the variables: `byte bir, float e, boolean f...`

Answer (score 0):

The example works because everything can be automatically converted to a String, and addition is left-associative.

The difference between a `char` and a `String` may not be obvious to you. `'C'` is a `char` literal, while `"C"` is a `String` literal (which can contain multiple chars).

Let's go through a few steps of the string concatenation in the example, showing conceptually how the addition is performed:

```
"H" + a + b + b + zero + d + "w" + zero + "r" + b + "d" + d + e + d + f;
"H3" + b + b + zero + d + "w" + zero + "r" + b + "d" + d + e + d + f;
"H31" + b + zero + d + "w" + zero + "r" + b + "d" + d + e + d + f;
"H311" + zero + d + "w" + zero + "r" + b + "d" + d + e + d + f;
"H3110" + d + "w" + zero + "r" + b + "d" + d + e + d + f;
```

...and so on. Every addition will always be a `String` + some other value, which is fine.

The addition in your code, on the other hand, tries to add incompatible types like `int` and `boolean`, which doesn't fly. Also, it tries to store the result in a `String` variable, which is not possible, because the result is not a `String`.